#  Run create/drop DB2 database commands for a specific user other than machine logged-in user

Tags: java, db2

```
db2 CREATE DATABASE XYZ

db2 DROP   DATABASE XYZ
```

These db2 commands which doesn't provide support to specify username/password while executing on db2cmd/db2clp for a specific user other than machine logged-in user. Hence result a exception

"SQL1092N  The requested command or operation failed because the user ID does not have the authority to perform the requested command or operation."

And when the same commands run as by choosing 'Run as different user', it works properly.

1. But I need to use same mechanism from Java code, but don't know how. Is it possible to open installed db2's clp as a different user form Java code??
2. Is it possible to associate username/password in create/drop commands?

Comment: Do you **have** to use db2cmd/db2clp? If you want to do it from java anyway, can't you just use `JDBC`?

Comment: @Sebastian_H create and drop command is the part of Db2 so why jdbc? i am using db2.

Comment: `JDBC` stands for `Java Database Connectivity`. Basically a universal API that allows you to connect to databases(DB2 among many others) and run statements on it. You can (or rather must) specify the user you want to connect with and then you can run your statements. If you are writing a Java application, you should check it out. It's much safer and more convenient than having your app call command line programs.

Comment: Sabastian, CREATE/DROP database are not the part of JDBC, these are the parts of database API only. You can't run JDBC statement for creating/droping database, it won't be executed.

Comment: @Kishore I did a (very) quick research via Google and found several tutorials explaining how to create databases via `JDBC`. These were all for `MySQL` however. So `JDBC` **can** execute such statements, if it's supported by the database. I also found a post claiming that in DB2 for LUW _create database_ is indeed only available on the command line, while in DB2 for z/OS it's supposed to also work as an SQL statement. I assume he uses DB2 for LUW, but I didn't know beforehand that it doesn't support the command via SQL. So, my bad if I made a useless suggestion.

Comment: I just want to ask you that if no database created initially (first time), then how would I then use jdbc for Create database command.
Reason: JDBC connection can only be established, if u specify a database name in connection URL, after then u can use statements to create tables/procedures etc, but if not database is there (initially), then how u will use JDBC?

Comment: @RTA In `JDBC` it's dependent on the subprotocol/drivers if you have to specify a database. You can see this here, for example:  
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html#db_connection_url  
Apparently DB2 always requires a database in the URL. Which, again, I wasn't aware off beforehand. I just assumed it would work and didn't know the limitations of DB2 in that matter. It would've been valid for a different type of database like MySQL though.

Comment: @Sebastian_H  Yes thats we are saying initially..it would b nice to comment or answer if u understood it well.

Comment: @RTA Yes, I see now what you tried to tell me. I definitely learned something, so thank you.

Answer (score 3):

From the CLP you can first `ATTACH` to the instance using whatever user ID you need, and then issue the `CREATE DATABASE` command.

If the instance is running on your local machine, you just attach like this:

```
$ db2 attach to db2inst1 user db2inst1
Enter current password for db2inst1: 

   Instance Attachment Information

 Instance server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 9.7.5
 Authorization ID       = DB2INST1
 Local instance alias   = DB2INST1
```

If the instance is running on a remote server, you attach to the "node name" that you have defined in your database catalog:

```
$ db2 list db directory

 System Database Directory

 Number of entries in the directory = 1

Database 1 entry:

 Database alias                       = SAMPLE
 Database name                        = SAMPLE
 Node name                            = SRV01
 Database release level               = d.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Remote
 Catalog database partition number    = -1
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =
```

In this example, the Node Name shown in the output from `list database directory` is `SRV01`, so you would attach using:  `db2 attach to srv01 user <username>`.

Comment: C:\> db2 attach to db2 user *** using ***
Saved my life!