# How to create/drop a database on DB2 through JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, db2, ddl

I have some test code using JDBC to connect to MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, and SQL Server, with only some minor differences between databases. I would like to run this test code as well on DB2. To start with a blank slate, and also test our database creation DDL, the tests start by creating a database (e.g. `CREATE DATABASE`), and end by deleting that database (e.g. `DROP DATABASE`).

I read a [comment from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276550/run-create-drop-db2-database-commands-for-a-specific-user-other-than-machine-lo#comment16472228_12276550) saying that, at least on DB2 for Linux, one can't run `CREATE DATABASE` and `DROP DATABASE` through JDBC, but only from the command line, which would be a bummer for running my integration tests on DB2. Is there really no way of creating, and then dropping a database through JDBC?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, a "database" in MySQL or SQL Server is closer to a schema in DB2.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is for only SQL. Create database or Drop database is not SQL, and for this reason that statement cannot be executed from JDBC. You can execute DB2 commands via Runtime class, or using JNI to use the DB2 API

- db2 create database command http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001941.html
- sqlecrea  API http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0001446.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. By "Runtime class", are you referring to a Java class/API that can be called from Java code? Where can I find more information about this API? I'd prefer not to use JNI, as this would create more portability, deployment, and configuration complications than I'd like.